# Git lfs configuration in .gitconfig for two different URLs

Tags: git, git-lfs

I have a unique situation where I work with multiple projects simultaneously. There are two git repositories for which I need to add LFS configuration in my server. Both projects use different LFS servers. Hence I need to enter two LFS configuration in .gitconfig, something like this.

```
[lfs "server1.com/project1.git"]
     url=https://<username>:<password>@lfs.server1.com
[lfs "server2.com/project2.git"]
     url=https://<username>:<password>@lfs.server2.com
```

Please let me know if this is a valid configuration. I tried but the server url is not getting used in filtering, please let me know what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

Git LFS doesn't currently support per-remote automatic filtering.  Part of the reason is that by the time the checkout occurs, which is when Git LFS is invoked, the information about which remote was being fetched from has been lost, so in most cases this is just not possible.  There are *some* cases, such as merges, where it would be possible to use per-remote filtering in the future because that information is passed down to Git LFS from Git, but that has not yet been implemented.

In the meantime, you can explicitly use `git lfs pull` or `git lfs fetch` with a remote to pull the data from the server you want.  If the LFS URL can be autodiscovered from the remote, then the best way to handle this is to simply avoid specifying the server and just use the plain remote name.

Answer (score 0):

You may have an answer by now, but in case anyone else is looking for a way to do this, use the `--config` option with `git clone`.

For example:

```bash
git clone .... --config lfs.url=https://user:passwd@server/path
```